# Removing a `tikzpicture` from a `\caption` in LyX

Tags: errors, pdftex, lyx

New info at the bottom!

Previous title: `LyX "incomplete \iffalse"`

Previous text:

> I'm new to LyX and TeX in general, so this might be a very easy
>   problem.
>
> I had made a TikZ image as a figure in my document, and it worked
>   fine. I wanted to add a caption, and learned that you have to put it
>   in a float to do that, so I moved it into a float (I'm not completely
>   sure what a float is, but I don't think that matters here; I put the
>   TeX code inside a TeX code block inside a figure float). Suddenly, it
>   doesn't work at all.
>
> Trying to render a preview makes it say "The external program pdflatex
>   finished with an error."  I looked at the log, as it suggested, which
>   says "! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 68." I
>   opened the file in notepad++ and looked at line 68; here's the
>   neighborhood of it:
>
> ```
>  65 \quotes_language english
>  66 \papercolumns 1
>  67 \papersides 1
>  68 \paperpagestyle default
>  69 \tracking_changes false
>  70 \output_changes false
>  71 \html_math_output 0
> ```
>
> I then tried ctrl-f for "iffalse" and got no results. I also tried a
>   search for "if", and only found the words "d**if**ferent" and
>   "spec**if**ications" used in my document body, as well as line 55
>   "\just**if**ication true"--so there isn't even an if statement
>   anywhere in this thing to cause that error!
>
> Apologies if this has already been asked. It seems there are a lot of
>   "incomplete \iffalse" questions on here, but I don't know enough about
>   TeX to know what applies to my situation; they all seem to say
>   "incomplete \iffalse with \somefunctionidon'trecognise" and I'm not
>   sure if any of these apply.

So, at the advice of user Torbjørn T., I looked at the code in the TeX preview panel in LyX itself (which I hadn't used before because it doesn't show line numbers; I hadn't realized it didn't just display the .lyx file) and found that the TikZ code had found its way into a caption block, so the full figure code reads

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill] (0,0) circle [radius=65mm];;
    \draw [white, fill=white] (0,0) circle [radius=60mm];;
    \draw [brown, fill=brown] (0,0) circle [radius=50mm];;
    \draw [->, thick] (0,0) -- (50mm,0);
    \node [below] at (25mm,0) {$a=50\si{mm}$};
    \draw [<->, thick] (50mm,0) -- (60mm, 0);
    \node [above] at (55mm, 0) {$b$};
    \node [below] at (55mm, 0) {10mm};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}
```

I cannot edit this in the TeX preview panel, and I'm not sure how to extricate the `tikzpicture` block from the `\caption` in LyX. Could someone explain how to do this?

Comment: The line numbers will refer to the generated LaTeX source file, not the `.lyx` file. Hard to say why this happens, I can't think of any reason why a `tikzpicture` should work outside a float but not inside it. Can you reduce your file to the smallest possible document that demonstrates the error, and add the LaTeX code to your question? (You can find the LaTeX code in View --> Code Preview Pane, select *Complete source* on the right side of the panel, if it isn't chosen already. Grab everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.)

Comment: While working on that I found that apparently it thinks the `tikzpicture` _is_ a caption...? It's put it inside a `\caption` block. I suspect this is what's causing the problem.

Comment: That might cause a problem, if the cause lies there, all you need to do is move the Tex code block outside the caption.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. See the edited question, could you provide some guidance?

Comment: When you add a figure in LyX, you get a figure inset, and inside it a caption inset. The caption is thus the inner box, I think it says “Figure 1” before it. When you moved the ERT, you placed inside the caption inset. It should be placed before the caption inset, but still inside the figure.

Comment: Ah, see, I interpreted the "figure 1:" lead-in as indicating "here is where you should put figure 1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing comments:

When one adds a figure float in LyX, one gets this:

[image]

Here, the outer frame (inset) represents the `figure` environment in LaTeX, so that is the float. The inner frame, right of "Figure 1:", where the cursor is placed, is a caption inset. The caption text goes in this inner inset.

So when you're about to add the image, `tikzpicture`, or whatever it is, to the figure, you should move the cursor outside the caption inset first. E.g. like this:

[image]

As for what a float is: The purpose of a float is to improve the page breaks in your document. If a figure is static, and it is just too large to fit on the current page, you'll end up with a page that is far from full. With floating environments, LaTeX can move big non-breakable things (like images) around, so instead of a half empty page, you get a page full of text, and the figure on the next page.

This is something that confuses a lot of new LaTeX users, leading to many questions about "my figure isn't where I put it". But there is, as mentioned, a purpose to it.

It is possible to turn off the floating mechanism for figures, by going to the settings for the figure inset (right click where it says *float: Figure*) and choosing *Here definitely*. There are other options as well, if you want to learn more about how influence float positioning, there is a very comprehensive answer in [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)